# How to boot to Ubuntu desktop not tty1-6

Tags: 11.10, boot, tty

I can't get into Ubuntu desktop,  only tty1-6. How do I make it boot to Ubuntu desktop?

I did try ctrl-alt-F7

Version:  Ubuntu 11.10 (the only os installed)

Very old PC:

> Dell
>
> Intel Inside Pentium 4
>
> 20gb hard drive
>
> No internet

Please Explain Step By Step, Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you type "startx" in the virtual terminal?

Comment: Unable to locate package startx

Comment: You don't have to do anything; it comes up by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have installed from the Ubuntu Server installation media, especially since it states that it's unable to locate the package. A GUI isn't installed by default with the server edition of Ubuntu. [This is the link to the 32-bit Alternate Install ISO](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu-releases/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso) for the Desktop edition, which is what would be appropriate for your Pentium 4 based system. (I linked to the Alternate ISO since I believe the Live installer needs more than 512MB of RAM to install, you didn't state how much RAM was in the system, just playing it safe).

Also, if you had a way to connect that machine to the internet, you could install the Ubuntu Desktop with the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I'll vote you up after 15 reputation. Lol, thanks again.